# Escaping untrusted data in php for my wordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have got a comment from someone superior to me who wants me to escape some comment in two php snippets which I have posted below. The problem is I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me by modifying the snippets.

Comment I got:

**Comment #1:**

**Validate and/or sanitize untrusted data before entering into the database. All untrusted data should be escaped before output.**

**Code Snippet #1:**

```
<?php 
if ( get_header_image() && !('blank' == get_header_textcolor()) ) { 
        echo '<div class="site-branding header-background-image" style="background-image: url(' . get_header_image() . ')">'; 
    } else {
        echo '<div class="site-branding">';
    }
?>
```

**Code Snippet #2:**

```
<?php
printf(
    /* translators: %1$s = text link: sangeet, URL: http://wordpress.org/themes/sangeet/, %2$s = text link: Kiran Kumar Dash, URL: https://twitter.com/TheKiranDash */
    __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s', 'sangeet' ),
                    '<a href="http://wordpress.org/themes/sangeet/" rel="nofollow">' . esc_attr( 'sangeet', 'sangeet' ) . '</a>',
    '<a href="https://twitter.com/TheKiranDash" rel="designer nofollow">' . esc_attr__( 'Kiran Kumar Dash', 'sangeet' ) . '</a>' ); 

?>
```

**Comment #2:**
esc all get_permalink() in content.php

**Code snippet #3**

```
<?php
if ( !is_single() ) {
    echo '<div class="index-box">';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<div class="small-index-thumbnail clear">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . __('Read ', 'sangeet') . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

**My approach:**

I used esc_url to esc the get_permalink() in the snippet. Shall I use esc_all? Or esc_url is just fine.

```
<?php
if ( !is_single() ) {
    echo '<div class="index-box">';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<div class="small-index-thumbnail clear">';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" title="' . __('Read ', 'sangeet') . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is more of a wordpress issue then a php one. you mention sanitizing information before reaching a database, i dont see none of that. I can provide a very good sanitation function, but im not sure what you need exactly

Comment: @iGNEOS. Thanks for the reply. I have done some sanitization. But I am getting trouble with escaping the html. Can you help me about escaping values while doing the output?

Comment: well in php, there is "strip_tags" function there is the "htmlentities" function others. Define what you mean by escaping? To prevent xss? sql injection? what is the purpose here?

Comment: I am new to PHP. Can you please have a look at the code snippet#1 and #2 above and see if I need anything to escape there.

Comment: to be perfectly honest with you, securing a website properly is a full-time job (and i dont trust wordpress or 3rd party themes) 

BUT

php function htmlentities may help you here, and strip_tags.

Im afraid to ask what you did for the database side, but when in comes to sanitation, its all in the input, if you clean it right, output is no worries, ill post my function for you as an answer, use it to clean input data at the beginning it should prevent 99% ish of XSS and sql injection etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:
PS. I didnt write this, only advanced it.

Usage:

```
$user = sanctify($_GET['user']);
```

Function:

```
function sanctify($data){
        // Fix &entity\n;
        $data = str_replace(array('&amp;','&lt;','&gt;'), array('&amp;amp;','&amp;lt;','&amp;gt;'), $data);
        $data = preg_replace('/(&#*\w+)[\x00-\x20]+;/u', '$1;', $data);
        $data = preg_replace('/(&#x*[0-9A-F]+);*/iu', '$1;', $data);
        $data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        // Remove any attribute starting with "on" or xmlns
        $data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?[\x00-\x20"\'])(?:on|xmlns)[^>]*+>#iu', '$1>', $data);
        // Remove javascript: and vbscript: protocols
        $data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([`\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*j[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iu', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $data);
        $data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*b[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iu', '$1=$2novbscript...', $data);
        $data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#u', '$1=$2nomozbinding...', $data);
        // Only works in IE: <span style="width: expression(alert('Ping!'));"></span>
        $data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?expression[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*+>#i', '$1>', $data);
        $data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?behaviour[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*+>#i', '$1>', $data);
        $data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:*[^>]*+>#iu', '$1>', $data);
        // Remove namespaced elements (we do not need them)
        $data = preg_replace('#</*\w+:\w[^>]*+>#i', '', $data);
        $data = str_replace('"','',str_replace("'","",$data));
            do{
            // Remove really unwanted tags
            $old_data = $data;
            $data = preg_replace('#</*(?:applet|b(?:ase|gsound|link)|embed|frame(?:set)?|i(?:frame|layer)|l(?:ayer|ink)|meta|object|s(?:cript|tyle)|title|xml)[^>]*+>#i', '', $data);
            }
            while ($old_data !== $data);
                // we are done...
                return $data;

        }
```

Comment: if this answer satisfies you, please click the checkmark to mark it the answer.